# Inserting An Overlaying Div on Slideshow

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, wordpress

So on http://www.breastcanceranswers.com/news/ we have a slider on the front page.

I am trying to put a div OVER the image but underneath the text. Essentially I want to put a semi transparent white overlay to filter the image on the slider, but then have the text stay as is so it pops more.

I've tried forcing divs on every angle to see if I can at least SEE the div and then hopefully put it in the right spot but nothing seems to be working. As usual Stack Overflow is my last resort - as I hate asking for help when the answer usually turns out to be easy.

My base questions are:

1) Based on View Source - am I missing where the div should go , you can search for the class="overlay"

2) Are there better tools I could be using that would help me seperate the divs so I can see where each is and then try inserting via that route?

ANy questions welcome, any help appreciated. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a little bit of a hack but I believe it does exactly what you're looking for. Inside your `<li class="clone" aria-hidden="true"...>`, add the following `#white_overlay` div:

```
<li class="clone" aria-hidden="true"..>
    <div class="post-info"..>
        <div name="white_overlay" style="height: 200%; width: 800%; opacity: .5;background: white;position: absolute;z-index: 1;margin-top: -50px;margin-left: -80px;"></div>
        <div class="entry-meta"></div>
    </div>
```

and then add this additional css:

```
.entry-meta {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 2;
}
```

This essentially works by creating a white div with 50% opacity, giving it `z-index=1` to move it "in front" of the images, and giving the `.entry-meta` class `z-index=2` to put the text in front of the `#white_overlay`. The height, width, and margin values were necessary to make sure all 5 of the images were covered (although you can tweak these values if you want) and the position values are necessary for z-index values to work correctly. There's lots to read on the topic of z-index and stacking context but here's a good start if you want more info:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Understanding_z_index/The_stacking_context?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=Understanding_CSS_z-index%2FThe_stacking_context

Comment: Thank you very much - this solved the issue. Appreciate the info, I was glad to have learn more about the z-index as it shows I've fell behind in CSS lol.  Thank you again

Comment: Glad to help! :) Also, regarding your second question about seeing different divs when you are messing around with the code, I usually use Chrome. When you right click and choose "inspect element" it brings up the developer tools. Putting your mouse over the html elements in the code will highlight those elements on the page. Super helpful if you've lost a div, etc. You can also change the css and see how it affects the page in real time.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to give your `.overlay` class position and force it to the top of it's parent element. This should be a start. Let me know how I can help from here...

```
.overlay {
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, .75);
    text-align: center;
    opacity: 1;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
}
```